# How can I find the perimeter of a concave pentagon?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, polygons

We know that a regular pentagon has five sides with identical lengths. But, the irregular pentagon has five sides with different angles. and moreover, the perimeter of a regular pentagon is 5a, where a is the side length of the regular pentagon. But how can I find out the formula of perimeter of an irregular concave pentagon? There is given a figure of a concave pentagon.

[image: Figure of a Concave Pentagon]

Here in the picture, the length of the AB and CD are Equal and the length of AB and BC are given. I have to find out the perimeter of the concave pentagon. I couldn't able to solve this anyway.

Comment: even without immediately realizing that there is an equilateral triangle, the trigonometry is simple: AE is simply `(BC/2) / sin(30º)`, or simply `BC`.

Answer (score 12):

**Hint:** Notice how the figure looks like a rectangle with an equilateral triangle cut out.

Comment: Looks like a rectangle. AB != BC.

Comment: @Holloway, *read* the problem descrption.

Comment: @alexis, please point out where it says length AB = BC

Comment: Well, the problem is a rearrangement of the edges of a regular pentagon, and those edges are all equal. But I'll grant you that the final paragraph calls that into question... and I see that other readers agree with you.

Answer (score 6):

Draw a line through $E$ parallel to $BC$.  What can you say about the triangles thus formed?

Answer (score 5):

The triangle $AED$ is equilateral and its base is $AD=BC=l$ so the perimeter is $3l+AB+CD$.

Comment: Why 3l ? could you specify that ?

Comment: is the length of AE , DE , BC are equal then ?

Comment: Because $AE=ED=BC$....the triangle $AED$ is equilateral and $AD$ (not drawn) is equal to $BC$.

Answer (score 5):

We know the triangle $AED$ is an equilateral triangle.
Therefore $AD=AE=DE=BC$.
Thus the perimeter is:$$P=3BC+2AB$$

Answer (score 2):

Perimeter of the retangle: `2AB + 2BC`

Perimeter of the equilateral triangle: `3BC`

Add the two together and remove the two BC lines (left edge of the retangle, left edge of the triangle): `2AB + 3BC`

Answer (score 2):

The perimeter formula is 5a. Since it's a square with an inscribed equilateral triangle, the other two (triangle) sides are equal to the 3rd -- and the remaining 3 sides of the square.

3 sides of a square + 2 of a triangle